# Name of a property in number theory

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, terminology

I want to find the name (or author of the proof) on the following property:
If $n\times m=\prod_i p_i$ where the $p_i$ are prime numbers, then $n=\prod_{i\in I}p_i$ for some subset $I$.

I know it is a classical result and I know how to prove it, I just need its name (or author).

Comment: I don't think this easy consequence of unique factorisation has a name of its own.

Comment: It's closely related to [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I thought it could be the rephrase of another property more than a consequence. But maybe you are right.